Pass external parameters from Google CCAI to Dialogflow CX for pre-populating user information
I'm working with Google CCAI (Contact Center AI) integrated with Dialogflow CX for an IVR system. I need to send external parameters from CCAI to Dialogflow CX to pre-populate user information retrieved from an API when the IVR calls a user. Specifically, I want to load this information as session parameters in Dialogflow CX.
What I've tried:

Using SIP headers
Using metadata options

However, neither of these approaches has been successful in passing the external parameters from CCAI to Dialogflow CX.
My goal:
When the IVR initiates a call to a user, I want to:

Fetch the user's information history from an external API
Pass this information to Dialogflow CX
Load the information as session parameters in Dialogflow CX

Questions:

What is the correct method to pass external parameters from Google CCAI to Dialogflow CX?
Is there a specific API or configuration in CCAI that allows for sending custom data to Dialogflow CX?
How can I ensure that the passed parameters are properly loaded as session parameters in Dialogflow CX?
Are there any limitations or best practices I should be aware of when passing data between CCAI and Dialogflow CX?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. If you need any additional information about my setup or what I've tried so far, please let me know.
